# Google Cloud API: how to save json response when using gcloud command

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am following the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/quickstart) page on how to send an API request to Google Cloud Video API.

As such I am using the gcloud command:

```
gcloud ml video detect-labels gs://cloud-ml-sandbox/video/chicago.mp4
```

Which returns the json response as intended. However, the response is just a printout to my console.

Now I would like to know if there is any way to save/write the json response to a file?

Comment: Add `> myfile.json` to your command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using linux, redirect the standard output to a file with >

With Windows, the same thing seems working. But I don't have a Windows OS for testing.

In addition, if you want to select only some parts in the response (only the business part and not the technical/protocol parts) you can use the --format param
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats